# What is console.php used for?

Tags: laravel

What is console.php used for in Laravel?

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Console Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of your Closure based console
| commands. Each Closure is bound to a command instance allowing a
| simple approach to interacting with each command's IO methods.
|
*/

Artisan::command('inspire', function () {
    $this->comment(Inspiring::quote());
})->describe('Display an inspiring quote');
```

Comment: like route file but for commands

Answer (score 0):

For creating php artisan commands, you can test it by typing in console `php artisan inspire` it will call `quote()` abstract method from `Inspiring` class.